# Turn Off Logging Ant Copy Task in AntRun

Tags: ant

I'm copying some files in an Ant Task within Maven and I cannot figure out how to tell ant not to log the fact that it is copying some files.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generateContext</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <copy file="src/main/context/context.xml"
              toDir="target/context/"
              overwrite="true" verbose="false">
              <filterset>
                <filter token="deploy.path" value="${deploy.path}" />
                <filter token="build.env.deployment.war.name"
                  value="${build.env.deployment.war.name}" />
              </filterset>
            </copy>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Every time I execute the task I see the following in the console:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generateContext) @ jive-web ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

 main:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/jmajors/turbinetrunk/jive/jive-web/target/context
```

Based upon the ant [copy task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) I wouldn't have thought that I would even need to worry about it, because it appears that logging is turned off by default, but that doesn't appear to be impacting whether or not something is logged.  Is there another setting that I should be paying attention to?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

When running Ant standalone, you would add the `-quiet` command line argument.

Here within Maven, it is the Maven AntRun plugin which is controlling the verbosity of Ant. As far as I can see, the verbosity of Ant is equal to the setup of the log of the Maven AntRun plugin.

I don't know much of Maven, if you can figured out how to set the level of log of the Maven AntRun plugin to "WARN", it will become quieter.

You could use the `-q` command line argument of Maven, but everything in Maven will become quieter.

Answer (score 0):

According the [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)-->running apache ant, you can add the -quiet command line flag to ant.  Update the run configuration to use this flag.  You could also change out the default logger for a log4j ant logger and suppress unwanted log entries in a log4j configuration: [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)-->loggers & listeners.